# How tall is Kevin Levin?

Tags: ben-10

In Ben 10, Kevin Levin is taller than both Ben and Gwen and can wear Grampa Max's clothing.

Does anyone know his height or a theory as to how tall he could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### As with most cartoons, the heights of characters are not presented consistently.

The [Bleach : Ultimate Alien Wiki](http://b-ua.wikia.com/wiki/Kevin_Levin) lists Kevin's height as approximately 5'7"-5'9"

**However...**

The [Cartoon Network website](http://www.cartoonnetwork.co.uk/show/ben-10/characters/fourarms) explicitly states that Fourarms is 12 feet tall...

[image]

Assuming that's accurate, then Ben's grandfather would need to be approximately 5'5'' tall for this picture to make sense...

[image]

Extrapolating from that, Ben is approximately 3'2'' and Kevin is therefore just under 3'6'' tall...

[image]

Which makes no sense.

Comment: Not to be rude or anything but what episode is this mentioned in, because if I am not mistaken he is supposed to be taller. If he is taller than ben and gwen they have to be at least 5'4 and 5 feet and that means that other characters have to be around 3 feet(some aliens do). It doesn't add up.

Comment: Also that wikia isn't reliable they said Kevin's education was N/A it is well known that in the episode "It isn't easy being Gwen" he asks Gwen to help him get a GED since he missed so much school as a child.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock - I'm assuming they're basing it on Ben's known height plus about four inches. As I said though, his height will be presented inconsistently.

Comment: And what would Ben's height be, if someones knows it put a credible source up or name the episode.

Comment: Fourarms is explicitly stated to be 12 feet tall on the Cartoon Network website; http://www.cartoonnetwork.co.uk/show/ben-10/characters/fourarms As you can see, Ben must be at least 6'5 if that's the case. http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110116183834/ben10/pt/images/3/37/Tetramand_Gwen.jpg Inconsistency, thy name is cartoon.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock - See latest edit. Kevin Levin is approximately 3'6''

Answer (score -1):

i would say in the original series ben is about 4'5 and gwen is about 4'8 so i will say kevin is about 5'1 ...due to the fact they are 10 years old.....in alien force or ultimate alien ben is about 5'11 , gwen is around 5'8 and kevin is around 6'3 or 6'4 depending on the situation with animated cartoon height isnt alwayse correct and stable but thats what i came up with do far

[image: image 1]

also

[image: image 2]

Comment: aside from ages, what are you basing these numbers on? people can be tall or short for their ages.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say he's around 5'8 or 6 feet tall

Comment: Hi LJ welcome to Sci-Fi Stackexchange, have you see the [tour]? On stack exchange we expect objective answers that are backed up with sources. We're not a discussion forum, so the answer you provided doesn't really fit here.